# Interquartile Rules to Replace Outliers in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, outliers

i'm facing an issue when replacing outliers with upper and lower boundary with Interquartile Rules, the kernel return an error saying "Must specify axis=0 or 1"

The code of defining the function of interquartile rules to replace outliers with upper and lower boundary as follow:

```
def iqr(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        if df[col].dtype != object:
            Q1 = df[col].quantile(0.25)
            Q3 = df.quantile(0.75)
            IQR = Q3 - Q1
            S = 1.5*IQR
            LB = Q1 - S
            UB = Q3 + S
            df[df > UB] = UB
            ddf[df < LB] = LB
        else:
            break
    return df
```

The dataframe is boston, which can be loaded from scikit learn

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
df = pd.DataFrame(load_boston().data)
df.columns = boston.feature_names
df
```

Then, i use the function to replace the numerical attributes outliers with upper or lower boundary

```
iqr(df)
```

But then it turns out with the value error

```
ValueError: Must specify axis=0 or 1
```

Looking for help, thank you!

Comment: Are there more lines of error messages?  It might help to include them because they often identify which line of your code is responsible for the problem.  That said, there seem to be several typos in your code so you might put in some print() statements to see what it thinks it is doing.  In particular I am suspicious of the Q3 line, which probably wants df[col].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the iteration through columns, you should always use df[col], and not df since you are working with only one column. so for example in your code:

```
Q3 = df.quantile(0.75)
```

should be

```
Q3 = df[col].quantile(0.75)
```

And

```
df[df > UB] = UB
```

should be

```
df.loc[df > UB,col] = UB
```

And so on ......

Without changing your function too much, this works:

```
def iqr(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        if df[col].dtype != object:
            Q1 = df[col].quantile(0.25)
            Q3 = df[col].quantile(0.75)
            IQR = Q3 - Q1
            S = 1.5*IQR
            LB = Q1 - S
            UB = Q3 + S
            df.loc[df[col] > UB,col] = UB
            df.loc[df[col] < LB,col] = LB
        else:
            break
    return df
```

Consider writing the function for just one column, and use `apply` :

```
def iqr(x):
    IQR = np.diff(x.quantile([0.25,0.75]))[0]
    S = 1.5*IQR
    x[x < Q1 - S] = Q1 - S
    x[x > Q3 + S] = Q1 + S
    return x

df.select_dtypes('number') = df.select_dtypes('number').apply(iqr)
```

Comment: Thank you so so much, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To help debug this code, after you load in `df` you could set `col` and then run individual lines of code from inside your `iqr` function.

```
import pandas as pd

# Make some toy data.  Could also load boston dataset.
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[-10, 100], b=[-100, 25]))
df

# Get the name of the first data column.
col = df.columns[0]
col

# Check if Q1 calculation works.
Q1 = df[col].quantile(0.25)
Q1

...
```